# IntelliJ includes test-classes from another maven module on classpath

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, classpath

I have a problem accessing resource file, when I run tests in IntelliJ. When I run the same tests from maven everything works as expected.

The maven3 project has 2 modules: database-module and webapp-module. webapp-module depends on database-module.

Files:

```
database-module/src/main/resources/dataSource.xml
database-module/src/test/resources/dataSource.xml
database-module/src/test/java/org/example/DataSourceTest.java
webapp-module/src/test/java/org/example/HomeControllerTest.java
```

There is a test class DataSourceTest in database-module. The test uses dataSource.xml from classpath.

DataSourceTest.java contains:

```
@Value("classpath:dataSource.xml")
private Resource myDataSource;
```

The annotation @Value is org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value.

When I run the test, the variable myDataSource contains the data from src/test/resources. It works well for maven and for IntelliJ.

I have another test HomeControllerTest in webapp-module. The test also uses dataSource.xml in the same way as DataSourceTest. However there is a difference in running the test from maven and from IntelliJ:

If I run HomeControllerTest from maven, it works as expected: it uses database-module/src/main/resources/dataSource.xml.
If I run HomeControllerTest from IntelliJ, it uses database-module/src/test/resources/dataSource.xml.

The file dataSource.xml is present only in database-module, there is no dataSource.xml in webapp-module.

I printed out the classpath in IntelliJ while running HomeControllerTest and I was surprized that test-classes from database-module is present, even though HomeControllerTest is part of webapp-module.

The classpath (when the test is run from IntelliJ):

```
C:/myproject/database-module/test-classes
C:/myproject/database-module/classes
C:/myproject/webapp-module/test-classes
C:/myproject/webapp-module/classes
```

The tests use JUnit4.

Why is there database-module/test-classes on classpath when I invoke the test from webapp-module?
How can I change IntelliJ behaviour to match the maven way of constructing classpath?

Comment: Do you have a dependency from your webapp module to your database module?

Comment: Yes, I do. When I perform "mvn clean install", the database-module is built first, next is the webapp-module. The HomeControllerTest uses dataSource.xml from the database-module, so the dependency is clearly there. However, when I use IntelliJ, the HomeControllerTest picks up the wrong dataSource.xml (ie. database-module/src/test/resources/dataSource.xml instead of database-module/src/main/resources/dataSource.xml).

Comment: Are you sure there is not a dependency in webapp-module on database-module test-jar?
What is the value in Intellij Run/Debug Configuration -> Your test -> Use classpath of module

Comment: I am sure there is not a dependency in webapp-module on database-module test jar as I get the expected result when I build the project with maven. The setting "Use classpath of module" is disabled, when I select "Test kind": "All in package" and "Search for tests": "In whole project". The problem turned out to be IntelliJ issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be an issue with IntelliJ version 13. I tested the described problem and my test works when I run only one particular test. However when I try to run all the test ("Test kind": "All in package" and "Search for tests": "In whole project") I get into the trouble described in the question.

According to JetBrains JIRA the issue is fixed in IntelliJ version 14 - I didn't check.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123962