# When running unit test in IntelliJ 2020.3, reflection sees other modules' test classpath

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project in IntelliJ Idea. The project includes a data-model module where an unit test uses reflection to make sure model classes are well formed. This test passes when running `mvn clean install`, but when I run it in IntelliJ, the test fails. The output indicates that dummy classes under another module's test folder cause this failure.

Another test fails because Spring application initialization loads a service from another module but the service refers to classes not in the current module's classpath. That test also works in maven. A possibly related issue is that, in another module, "Run All Tests" causes an error message indicating no tests were found.

I have tried reloading all Maven projects, invalidating caches and restarting, and deleting the IntelliJ cache by hand. By now, I believe I have gone through all permutations of these.

I found a similar question from [five years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299618/intellij-includes-test-classes-from-another-maven-module-on-classpath), where the answer is that this was an issue with the version of IntelliJ in use then. That is probably not the case here, because I'm using a newer version and this problem has appeared recently without upgrading Idea.

Is there a way to fix this, or have I run into a bug in IntelliJ that should be reported to JetBrains?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly happens as you did not say how you run the tests, what is the test code and what error you are getting. But I suspect that issue could be in a different classpath when you run from IDE. What run configuration do you use? What modules is selected in the run configuration for the classpath?

Comment: @Andrey I had the test file selected and pressed "run" from the context menu. I'd think it would use the default configuration to run the test.

Comment: Please try the latest IDE version (2021.2.2) to see if you can see this issue. You could also check the classpath printed in the Run window when running this test compared to `File | Project Structure | Modules | <module_name> | Dependencies`. If none of them help, you may report this issue to JetBrains with a sample project if possible.

Comment: It appears Intellij is running multi-module tests using a "global" classpath, which results in test resources leaking from one module to another. There is no fix for this currently AFAIK even though there are a number of bug reports in Intellij's issue tracker related to this.